# How can I edit the following Powershell code to rename and append a resolution to MP4 video files?

Tags: powershell, rename

Does anyone know how to edit the code I found below so that 1080p or 720p is on the end of the file name. I want my file names to go from this

```
Black.Panther.2018.1080p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AM].txt
Sonic.The.Hedgehog.1920.1080p.WEBRip.x264.AAC-[YTS.MX].txt
Fun.with.Dick.and.Jane.2005.1080p.BrRip.x264.YIFY.txt                                              
The.Italian.Job.2003.720p.BrRip.x264.YIFY.txt                                                  
The.Legend.Of.Tarzan.1916.720p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AG].txt
```

**To this...**

```
Black Panther 2018.1080p.txt
Sonic The Hedgehog 1920 1080p.txt
Fun with Dick and Jane 2005 1080p.txt                                              
The Italian Job 2003 720p.txt                                                  
The Legend Of Tarzan 1916 720p.txt
```

This is the code I am using:

```
Set-Location "X:\AUTOMATED_FILM_&_TV_SHOWS\2_SEPERATING_FOLDER\MOVIES"
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object{$_.BaseName -Match '(.*?\.(19|20)\d{2})\..*'} | Rename-Item -NewName {($_.BaseName -replace '(.*?\.(19|20)\d{2})\..*','$1')+$_.Extension}
dir -Filter *.mp4 | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.replace("."," ") + $_.Extension }
```

Comment: What research have you done? Renaming files is pretty basic and there's lots of instructions available for renaming files

Comment: @music2myear so far I've tried to edit the code and add 1080p and 720p where "19|20" are. That didn't work.Then I looked up basic renaming. But I can't figure out how to keep everything before the "p". So the code still removes the periods but keeps the garbage after 1080p/720p.

Comment: Basically This. **The Titan 2018 1080p WEBRip x264-[YTS AM].mp4** Instead of this **The Titan 2018 1080p.mp4**

Comment: are you wanting to just trim away everything starting @ `WEBRip`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes! exactly!

Comment: @LexPointOh - please take a look at the Answer i posted. it seems to cover what you want done. [*grin*]

Comment: Any file manager that supports mass rename can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do it:   ( Remove `-WhatIF` after test run )

```
Set-Location 'X:\AUTOMATED_FILM_&_TV_SHOWS\2_SEPERATING_FOLDER\MOVIES'
Get-ChildItem -Name | ForEach {
    If ( $_ -match '(^.+(?:720p|1080p)).+(\.\w{3})' ) {
        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_ -NewName ( $matches[1].Replace('.',' ') + $matches[2] ) -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Name construction tested with this code:

```
'The.Titan.2018.720p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4',
'Avatar.2018.1080p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4' | ForEach {
    If ( $_ -match '(^.+(?:720p|1080p)).+(\.\w{3})' ) {
        echo ( $matches[1].Replace('.',' ') + $matches[2] )
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
PS C:\...\keith>ren test.reg atesty.reg^C
PS C:\...\keith>cd \
PS C:\> 'The.Titan.2018.720p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4',
>> 'Avatar.2018.1080p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4' | ForEach {
>>     If ( $_ -match '(^.+(?:720p|1080p)).+(\.\w{3})' ) {
>>         echo ( $matches[1].Replace('.',' ') + $matches[2] )
>>     }
>> }
The Titan 2018 720p.mp4
Avatar 2018 1080p.mp4
PS C:\>
```

Comment: I tried the output code that you provided, that worked perfectly. But when I try the code that has **WhatIf** it get this error. **Rename-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.**

Comment: Sorry. Was testing two different approaches. Code has been corrected.

Comment: Keith, I'm basically new to Powershell so I'm still trying to comprehend a lot of this. Bear with me lol. Idk what I'm doing wrong. I edited my initial question to reflect the actual files. After I run the code 3 out of the 5 files get this. `Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'The.Legend.Of.Tarzan.1916.720p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AG].txt' does not exist. At line:5 char:9 `. Those 3 don't get renamed but the other 2 do.

Comment: Special charaters (brackets) in filename! Have to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter instead of the (positional) `-Path`. Will edit my code again.

Comment: KEITH! I could kiss you! lol Thanks so much! That did it! you're awesome! I see what you're saying because there were brackets and other characters it had to use the Literal Path. I'll have to look that up as well. Thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

this seems to do the job. [*grin*] it presumes the files will all have `WEBRip` in the file name AND that string is where you want to split the base name of the file. the comments seem adequate, but please feel free to ask if any of the code is non-obvious.

```
$SourceDir = "$env:TEMP\LexPointOh"

#region >>> create files to work with
#    when ready to do this with real data point the "$SourceDir" to your real data
if (-not (Test-Path $SourceDir))
    {
    $Null = mkdir -Path $SourceDir
    }
@(
    'The.Titan.2018.720p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4'
    'Avatar.2018.1080p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4'
    ) |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Null = New-Item -Path $SourceDir -Name $_ -ItemType 'File' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
        }
#endregion >>> create files to work with

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Filter '*.mp4' -File |
    Where-Object {
        # skip files that already end with a resolution value
        $_.BaseName -notmatch '\d{1,}p$'
        }

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    # match everything from the start of the string up to & including the "<digit><p><dot>"
    #    the "$Null" is there to dump the unwanted output of the match operator
    $Null = $FL_Item.BaseName -match '^.+\dp\.'
    # get the 1st match from the "$Matches" automatic variable
    #    trim away any trailing dot
    #    split on the remaining dots
    #    join the results with spaces
    #    finally, add the file extension
    $NewName = ($Matches[0].TrimEnd('.').Split('.') -join ' ') + $FL_Item.Extension
    $FullNewName = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath $NewName

    if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $FullNewName))
        {
        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName -NewName $NewName #-WhatIf
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Warning ('    A file named [ {0} ] already exists in {1}' -f $NewName, $SourceDir)
        }
    }
```

output when there is already an `Avatar 2018 1080p.mp4` file in the $SourceDir` ...

```
WARNING:     A file named [ Avatar 2018 1080p.mp4 ] already exists in C:\Temp\LexPointOh
```

there is no output otherwise. you may want to add such - or record the fail/success to a file for later use.

Comment: Lee_Dailey, Thanks for your input. This seems fairly complex and I'm pretty new to Powershell. I'll have to do some research on Split.

Comment: @LexPointOh - you are welcome! you may want to start with `Get-Help about_Split` and then - perhaps - use the MSDocs website for some more info on the idea. the string in the `-split` operators target is what things get split on. if you use the `.Split()` method, it splits on _each character_, not on the whole string.

Comment: Oh yea! I almost forgot about `about_`, I'll check that out. Update! Your code looks like it only removes files that have **WEBRip** and I want it to remove **anything** after 720p or 1080p aside from the extension. Unless I'm reading the code wrong?

Comment: @LexPointOh - the WEBRip thing is why i asked you about that. i will go back and see what i can do with your revised requirement. ///// check the new version ... [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look.

Comment: @LexPointOh - you are most welcome! glad to have helped somewhat ... [*grin*]